# Longest path between two nodes of a graph

Tags: graphs

I have a graph $G$ (NOT directed). $SP$ is one of the shortest paths between $a$ and $b$ ($a$ and $b$ are nodes of $G$). $e$ is the edge of $SP$ between the nodes $j$ and $k$ ($j$ is before $k$ if we go from $a$ to $b$). If I remove $e$ from $G$, in the new graph there is a path between $a$ and $b$.

Can I say that, in the given $G$, there is at least a longest path between $a$ and $b$ that does not contain $e$?

Comment: Suppose $G$ is linear graph, after removing $e$ there is no path between $a,b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (assuming you meant that we can choose $e$ freely. If it isn't the case, the answer is "no").

Let $P_1:=a\rightarrow v_1\rightarrow v_2\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow b$ be the shortest path.

By your assumption, that there is still a path between $a$ and $b$ even if we remove some edge $e=(v_i,v_{i+1})$, we get that there is another path $P_2:= a\rightarrow u_1\rightarrow u_2\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow b$ which has at least one different edge, hence $P_2\neq P_1$.

By our assumption, $P_1$ is a shortest path and hence $len(P_1)\le len(P_2)$. Now, let $P$ be a longest path from $a$ to $b$. Notice, that we know that $len(P)\ge len(P_2)$ since it is maximal.

Now, lets split into two cases:

1. $len(P_2)>len(P_1)$. In this case, we get that $len(P)\ge len(P_2)>len(P_1)$ and hence $P\neq P_1$. Therefore there is a longest path $P$ which is not $P_1$
2. $len(P_2)=len(P_1)$. In this case, either that $len(P)>len(P_1)$ (and thus $P\neq P_1$ just as we did before), or $len(P)=len(P_1)$. In this case, we get that $len(P_2)=len(P)$ and hence $P_2$ is a longest path, while still we know that $P_2\neq P_1$ and hence there exists a longest path which is not $P_1$.

Therefore, there must be some path $P\neq P_1$ which is a longest path.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. You show that there is a longest path different than $P_1$ which is a longest path, but that doesn't mean it doesn't contain $e$? Plus, if the answer to the question was "yes", wouldn't that give a polynomial time algorithm to find a longest path? (which is NP-Hard)

Comment: Suppose $G$ is linear graph, and $a,b$ are left most and right most nodes, so after removing $e$ there is no path between $a,b$.

Comment: @Tassle yea. From what I understood in your question, you didn't restrict this edge $e$ to be anything specific. Assuming the paths are simple (if they aren't then there isn't even a longest path to begin with), then there is an edge in $P_1$ that is not in $P$: choose it to be $e$. If you meant that we are given $e$, then the answer changes: it is not correct. There is even a simple counter-example :)

Comment: @MohammadRostami We *assumed* that there is another path from $a$ to $b$ after removing $e$

Comment: Also @Tassle it wont solve an NP-hard question since I didn't tell you how to find this path, I just proved it exists. Finding it is a totally different question - a much harder one to say the least.

Comment: @nirshahar Ok, if we have a path between $a$ and $b$ other than the shortest one, this implies that there is an edge $e$, like described in the question, that does not belong to at least one of the longest paths between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @MarioGiambarioli Yes, if our path is simple (which is a common assumption), meaning that there isn't a vertex repeating. Otherwise we are only guaranteed that there is some edge in a longest path that is not in $P_1$

Comment: @nirshahar Okay, I understood the question as: given any edge $e$ on the shortest path whose deletion does not disconnect $a$ and $b$, is there always a longest path which does not contain $e$? Then what I meant was if the answer to that was yes then the following algorithm would find a longest path in polynomial time: Find a shortest path, find an edge $e$ on the path which does not disconnect $a$ and $b$ (if possible), delete it, repeat these three steps until there is no more valid edge $e$ to delete. The only path left would be a longest (simple) path.

Comment: @Tassle no. For starters, if you specify the edge $e$ beforehand - there is no guarantee that it wont be in the longest path. In addition, even if by change the first $e$ in the shortest path wasn't in the longest, the next edge you remove might be problematic (there *will* be a "good" edge, but you won't know which one it is!)

Comment: @nirshahar There is a misunderstanding here, I agree with you. I'm saying that not every edge is good, as otherwise we could solve longest path in poly-time. Of course one could simply give a counter-example, but I'm just clarifying my original comment (where I implied that you didn't answer the question as I understood it, i.e. "does the property hold for every non-disconnecting edge e?")